# Sort list and select object based on order by

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a `List<MyClass>` with `Status` and `Date` fields. I want to return a single `MyClass` where the `Status = X`.

The problem is there could be more than one in the list, in which case I want to sort on `Date` and return the latest one.

Can this be done in LINQ in a single expression?

Comment: `list.Where(x => x.Status == X).OrderBy(x => x.Date).Last();`

Comment: Or MaxyBy from MoreLINQ: list.Where(x => x.Status == X).MaxBy(x => x.Date).First()

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov You'd better add your suggestion as answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambda expression:

```
var yourResult = dbo.YourList.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Date).FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Status == 'X');
```

Comment: What is the point of sorting *first* and only then making selection ? What would happen if there is 1M records ?

Comment: It will save one extra check, however, for the larger list, it may reduce performance fractionally.

Comment: suppose 1M records with 90% of status 'X'.

Comment: Don't forget that checking in a loop is an `O(N)` operation while best sorting algorithms have complexity of `O(N*log(N))`

Answer (score 1):

If `list` already located at memory try this:

```
var answer = list.Where(x => x.Status == X).OrderBy(x => x.Date).LastOrDefault();
```

At case of Entity Framework try another approach:

```
var answer = context.Table.Where(x => x.Status == X).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It is just implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

So you a sequence of `MyClass` objects and an object `X`, and you want to find the newest `MyClass` object that has a value for `Status` equal to `X`

```
var result = myList.Where(myItem => myItem.Status == X)
                   .OrderByDescending(myItem => myItem.Date)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this will work, the sorting is not very efficient: after you've find the first element, it sorts the 2nd, 3rd, etc, while you know it will not use these other elements, so why sort them? If you use `Aggregate` you will only have to enumerate once

```
var result = myList.Where(...)
    .Aggregate( (newestItem, nextItem) => (newestItem.Date < nextItem.Date) ? 
           newestItem : nextItem);
```

This puts the first element in newestItem and scans the rest of the list. If any nextItem has a new data, then put this next item in newestItem, otherwise do not change newestItem. At the end return newestItem, which is the one with the newest date that you want.

This works only if you are **certain that there is at least one remaining item** after the where. If it must also work with empty lists, consider creating an extension function:

```
static TResult GetNewestOrDefault<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
   Func<Tsource, DateTime> dateSelector)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {   // at least one element; initialize newest:
        TSource newestElement = enumerator.Current;
        DateTime newestDate = dateSelector(newest);

        // scan the rest of the sequence and check if newer:
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Tsource nextElement = enumerator.Current;
            Datetime nextDate = dateSelector(nextElement);

            // if next element has a newer date, remember it as newest:

            if (newestDate < nextDate
            {
                newestElement = nextElement;
                newestDate = nextDate,
            }
        }
        // scanned all elements exactly once
        return newestElement;
    }
    else
       // empty sequence, return default
       return default(TResult);
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass result = myList.Where(myItem => myItem.Status == X)
                       .GetNewestOrDefault();
```

This will scan your sequence exactly once.